# Difference between obtaining object via getter vs via repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have these 2 entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    List<Order> orderList;

    /* getters and setters */

}

@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    /* getters and setters */

}
```

And this repository:

```
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Long> {
    List<Order> findByUser(User user);
}
```

Now if I have `user` which is a managed entity and want to get list of orders that belong to that `user` I can do that in 2 ways:

Method 1:

```
@Autowired
OrderRepository orderRepository;

List<Order> orderList = orderRepository.findByUser(user);
```

Method 2:

```
List<Order> orderList = user.getOrderList();
```

Is there any difference between these 2 methods? When should I use method 1 and when should I use method 2?

Thanks

Comment: If you happen to have a reference to a User, you'd probably use method 2.  Otherwise you might do either.

Comment: @cricket_007 no, there's none. If the orders are already in the session the repository will return them as they are in the session, even though it uses a query to find them. There shouldn't be any difference anyway, due to transaction isolation.

Comment: @cricket_007 You are right the way it is written, you need a user in both cases!  But I could imagine findByUser taking just a primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the exact configuration of fetch strategy and lazy loading, there might be a difference in when and how the data is actually loaded from the database. But this is not what should drive your decision, which access-path you are using.

A very central idea behind Spring Data is that of the Aggregate as described in [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215). There should be one Repository per Aggregate. So the question becomes: Are `User` and `Order` part of the same Aggregate? If one assumes that you adhered to the idea behind Spring Data, the fact that there are repositories for `User` and `Order` means, they are both Aggregate Roots and therefore can't be part of the same Aggregate. Also, therefore I would not use the reference and actually remove it (and I most certainly would remove the `Cascade.All`

But you obviously didn't make the design decision based on that argument, so you might as well decide that both shall be part of the same Aggregate and drop one of the repositories.